# Raster data are shown but can't be clipped or changed

Tags: qgis, data, clip, import

I'm struggling with a new problem on QGIS 3.30. Here's what I want to do:

I downloaded [raster data from my country in .img](https://vogis.cnv.at/geodaten/?service=files&t=418171be46e40175bfe171edfc4097dd&path=%2Fgelaendemodelle%2Fhoehenmodelle%2Fvlbg) and can easily import them from my local driver into QGIS. The problem: After I try to clip these data to a polygon (with tool: extract raster to layer mask) which is implanted to a shape layer I get this error message: `ERROR 4: Unable to open external data file: C:/...` How can QGIS not open it when I can still see the data on my screen?

In the end, the new layer is generated, but receives negative values in height.

The thing is that in the first try everything worked fine but since I wanted to try this in another project I can't work with the exact same raster data.

Edit: I import the raster data via drag and drop into QGIS, then I change the project KBS to 4326. After that I create a shape layer and draw my polygon to the spot I want to clip. If that is done I use tool 'Extend Raster to Layer Mask' (German: Raster auf Layermaske zuschneiden). As Input I use the .img file with KBS Transverse Mercator and as Output my Polygon with KBS 4326.

With this operation I end in the error message. Maybe it's just a small mistake I made, but I can't find it.

Does anyone know this problem and can help?

Comment: Please provide example data.

Comment: I used data from [link] (https://vogis.cnv.at/geodaten/?service=files&t=418171be46e40175bfe171edfc4097dd&path=%2Fgelaendemodelle%2Fhoehenmodelle%2Fvlbg)

Comment: I clipped one of those img files using a shapefile layer that was in the same projection and with a layer that was in EPSG:4326 and both worked and ouptut exactly the same values as the original img file
. Suggest you provide more details about exactly what you did and the clip layer you used (as edits to your question, not as comments)

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying. I edited the question.

Comment: Do you have spaces or special characters in the path? Sometimes they make issues.